# Peut-on omettre le "à" dans la phrase suivante ?

Tags: grammaire

Peut-on omettre le deuxième "à" dans la phrase suivante ?

> Il voulait offrir un cadeau à toutes les filles et **(à)** tous les garçons de sa classe

Answer (score 1):

Oui, c'est plus rare que de le laisser mais on peut l'omettre. On peut aussi simplifier le tout comme ceci :

> Il voulait offrir un cadeau à tous les élèves de sa classe.